# ListView não populada em todas as abas no primeiro acesso

Tags: android, listview

Olá, tenho uma aplicação Android de um questionário eletronico. Deve ser apresentado o mesmo questionário em abas, são 7 abas. O aplicativo baixa as questões da web de um XML.

Estou utilizando a biblioteca Volley para vazer o acesso ao questionário. Quando baixo o questionário e faço o parsing do XML gravo no banco e depois exibo em uma ListView.

O problema é que as questões não aprecem nas primeiras duas abas. Elas aparecem a partir da terceira. E ao acessar a terceira as questões aparecem na primeira e ao acessar a quarta elas aparecem na segunda. As outras funcionam normalmente.

O código dos fragments são esses:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

//declarações e onCreate...


private void requestQuestionario(){
    String tag_string_req = "req_questionario"; //tag para cancelar o request

    pDialog.setMessage("Carregando Questionário...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            RequestContract.XMLQuestionarioContract.XML_QUESITIONARIO_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response = " + s);

            //TODO -- Tratar Response
            InputStream xml = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes());
            try {
                HashMap questionario = XmlParser.parse(xml);
                List<Questao> questoes = (List) questionario.get("questoes");

               //insere questoes no banco....


                QuestionarioCache cache = QuestionarioCache.newInstance();
                cache.setQuestoes(questoes);


                cache.getAdapter(getApplication()).notifyDataSetChanged();


            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            hideDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

           //Carrega as questões existentes no banco....
        }
    });

    requestQueue = RequestManager.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();

    stringRequest.setTag(tag_string_req);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}


}
```

Fragment com a ListView

```
public class ListaQuestoesActivity extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = ListaQuestoesActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private View v;
private TextView textView;
private ListView listView;

private QuestionarioCache cache;

private int dia;

// onCreate....

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_questoes, container, false);

    textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_dia_qionario);
    textView.setText("Dia " + dia);

    carregarListaQuestoes();

    return v;

}


private void carregarListaQuestoes(){
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_questoes);

    cache = QuestionarioCache.newInstance();

    listView.setAdapter(cache.getAdapter(getActivity()));


}
}
```

Quando uso uma lista estática ela aparece em todas as abas normalmente:

```
String[] list = {"Ola", "Mundo", "Foo", "Bar"};

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Alguém sabe como corrigir?

Comment: verifique se o seu QuestionarioCache é o mesmo em todos os Fragments. Talvez cada uma das suas tabs esteja criando o seu próprio cache e o tempo de carga para cada uma delas pode ser diferente, já que o IO é assíncrono. Pelo código do Main, o seu cache parece ser uma instância local.

Comment: QuestionarioCache é um Singleton, pode ser esse o problema?

Comment: Este artigo do Jon Skeet é uma excelente referencia para escrever perguntas legais: http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints